# How to copy a full directory structure in unix WITH SYMBOLIC LINKS & without any files?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am trying to create a new directory which has the whole replica of another directory structure. Lets say the directory one is A and directory two is B. In this case, I want the whole directory structure of A inside B wherein I do not copy any files but do consider and copy all symbolic links.

In this way, I want to take care of local and remote files altogether. 
i.e.
            `cd <A_directory>`
            `find . -type d | cpio -pdvm <B_directory>`

this helps to get me the whole of A directory structure inside B without symbolic links. 
AR: Have to add symbolic links and directories properly on top of this?

The rsync does not handle symbolic links and takes a lot of time. This question is different from just a normal rsync.

Comment: "_rsync does not handle symbolic links_" -- um? See for instance [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/799354/rsync-and-symbolic-links).  Or, many other links from googling "rsync and symbolic links" (for example).  The  "fault" that `rsync` has is that it does too much...

Comment: "_rsync ... and takes a lot of time._" -- That's practically a side comment in your question -- can you be (way) more specific, to substantiate that? Like, tell us how much you copy with it and how long it takes, and show how you do it. That would amount to a whole question of its own.